# Convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^{n}\cdot n!}{n^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have to show the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^{n}\cdot n!}{n^{n}}$$
converges. I know it does and I tried to use the ratio test, but in the final limit, I got
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2i\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]^{-1}$$
which results at
$$\frac{2i}{e}$$
and I don't know if I can't say it's smaller than 1 because of the imaginary unity.

Comment: When doing the ratio test, the custom is to consider $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$.

Comment: I always make this mistake! lol thanks!

Comment: You can go for the absolute series.Then the term i will automatically vanish.

Comment: You should have $(1+1/n)^{-n}$, which is probably a typo.

Comment: Note that $||i|| = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By CS and Stirling we have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^{n}\cdot n!}{n^{n}}\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cdot n!}{n^{n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi n} \, n^n \, e^{\frac{1}{12n}}}{n^{n} \, e^n} \leq \, e^{\frac{1}{12}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi n} }{e^n} \, .$$

Regarding your actual question you can do the same again, but using CS first before you apply the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^{n}{n!}}{n^n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{n}{n!}}{n^n}\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n{n!}\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n{n!}\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a)_{n}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b)_{n}
\end{align*}
1)we have
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((a)_{n}+i(b)_{n})$ is convergent $\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$convergens \
So
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n{n!}\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n}\\
&=(\sum_{n\in 2N^*}^{}\frac{2^n(n!)\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n}+\sum_{n\in 2N+1}^{}\frac{2^n(n!)\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n})\\
&=\sum_{n\in 2N^*}^{}\frac{2^n(n!)\cos(n\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^n}\
=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2p}((2p)!)\cos(p\pi)}{(2p)^{2p}}\
\end{align*}
$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|=|\frac{2^(2p+2)(2p+2)!\cos(\pi(p+1))(2p)^{2p}}{(2p+2)^(2p+2)\cos(\pi(p))2^(2p)(2p)!}|=4|\frac{2p+1}{2p+2}||(1-\frac{1}{p+1})^{2p}|$\
$\lim_{n\mapsto\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|=\frac{4}{e^2}$
After calculating the limit, we find$\frac{4}{e^2}$ so this series is converjent .and the second part in the same way
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$is convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$is convergent $\implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i)^n(n!)}{n^n}$ is convergent

Comment: I don't know where went wrong as your latex formatting is really messed up, but I am sure that your $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is wrong. It should be $\frac{(2p+1)(2p+2)}{(p+1)^2}\cdot (1+\frac{1}{p})^{-2p}$ which tends to $\frac{4}{e^2}<1$ and thus by the radio test $a_n$ converges.

Comment: Yes, I rushed in the end to calculate the limt, and I did not give her any attention, thanks for the note, Brother

Comment: I modified that .. Thanks, Brother